# nginx: Do not require Basic Authentication only if http request is OPTIONS

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication, http-options-method

The Authorization Header is not sent with an HTTP OPTIONS Request. I would like disable this authentication only when the request is OPTIONS and leave it on for other requests. Here is the relevant piece of config code I have at the moment.  cannot seem to see why it does not work. I always get a 401 Unauthorized Error on OPTIONS request.

```
    location ~ /foo/bar
    {

      if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
        set $auth_basic "off";
      }
      if ($request_method != OPTIONS)
      {
        set $auth_basic "Resctricted";
        set $auth_basic_user_file /var/www/.htpasswd;
      }
      auth_basic $auth_basic;
      auth_basic_user_file $auth_basic_user_file;
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

It looks like it is an old post, but found this solution :

Put the following configuration inside "location" and remove any auth_basic from server. This will work

```
  location / {
    # Your node proxy configuration for example #

    # Make options requests work #
    limit_except OPTIONS {
      auth_basic "Restricted access zone";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pass/protected;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the simplest answer, confirmed that it works.
It's really not clear from the nginx documentation that limit_except will achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to deal with this is allow nginx to handle the `OPTIONS` request:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  example.com;
    root /var/www;

    auth_basic "Resctricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/.htpasswd;

    location / {
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.com";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
            add_header Content-Length 0;
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
            return 200;
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow `OPTIONS` to get a response without requiring authentication:

```
scott@Carl www $ curl -i -X OPTIONS http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 17 Jun 2017 00:09:52 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain

scott@Carl www $ curl -i http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 17 Jun 2017 00:09:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 188
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Resctricted"

<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I came up with this with your help. Woudn't this be right? The authentication code have to be there because this is the only location that requires it. I still get a 401 Unauthorized.

    `location ~ /foo/bar/
    {

      if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {

        ...
        return 200;
      }

      auth_basic "Restricted";
      auth_basic_user_file /var/www/.htpasswd;
    }`

Comment: thx @sjdaws - finally after hours I got right answer that "Methods: OPTIONS" cannot by behind AUTH 

Comment: The key to this answer is in the `return 200;`, which doesn't let the suthentication handler take over once the response is done. I had that part missing and authentication was being enforced even for OPTIONS